# Polling with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I tried to solve polling with the information on this page: https://bigbite.net/polling-with-redux/

```
// inside a saga
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
...

export function* pollStuffSaga() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const response = yield call(fetchStuff);
      const items = handleResponse(response);
      yield put(onFetchStuffSuccess(items));
      yield delay(30000); // 30 sec
    } catch (e) {
      yield put(onFetchStuffFailure(e));
    }
  }
}

function* pollWatcherSaga() {
  while (true) {
    yield take(START_POLLING); // I call start polling from componentDidMount
    yield race([call(pollArchiveSaga), take(STOP_POLLING)]); // And I call stop polling from componentWillUnmount
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield call(pollWatcherSaga); // fired when saga is injected
}
```

The problem I have now is that I see in network that my service gets called too many times. It is called all the time. Should not my delay prevent it to call my fetchStuff in the next round inside while? Should it not wait for 30 sec before the code moves on?

Comment: Never mind. This worked just fine! The problem was inside handleResponse function

Comment: Please provide your solution so that others can benefit from it if they encounter similar problems.

Comment: @codekaizer my question is my solution. The problem was inside my handleResponse function, which is just a function that format the response to the propper format for my "items" constant

Comment: what I meant was to post your solution as an answer. mark it as an answer so that the viewers will know this question is already answered.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have made a comment on the line which was the problem. When I fixed my "homemade method", handleResponse(response), then my pulling logic worked. So just look away for how I handle my response inside that method, and this code will work with corresponding reducer and actions etc:

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
...

export function* pollStuffSaga() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const response = yield call(fetchStuff);
      const items = handleResponse(response); // The problem was inside this function
      yield put(onFetchStuffSuccess(items));
      yield delay(30000);
    } catch (e) {
      yield put(onFetchStuffFailure(e));
    }
  }
}

function* pollWatcherSaga() {
  while (true) {
    yield take(START_POLLING);
    yield race([call(pollArchiveSaga), take(STOP_POLLING)]);
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield call(pollWatcherSaga);
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem and my code looks similar. I don't get how handleResponse has influence on how often the polling is triggered. My timeout is not working too. Maybe you could improve your answer by providing more detail how handleResponse created the problem and how you fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I changed the delay function from 'redux-saga/effects' to my own delay function and it worked.

`const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));`

and used it like this:

`yield delay(4000);`